# Time zones to consider for new moderator

Tags: discussion, election

There was some discussion in [an answer](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3503/8363) to a meta question a while ago, mentioning that the time zones the mods live in might play a role in how fast flags and the likes are treated.

In the view of the upcoming election, what time zones would be preferable for the new mod?

Comment: FWIW: JoErNanO, Jonathan Reez, Pixie, and Ulkoma are all based in Europe; Mark Mayo and jamessug are in Sydney; cnst is in California; toing_toing is in Sri Lanka; and MastaBaba appears to be in Brazil.

Answer (score 12):

I'm based in Switzerland, mindcorrosive in Bulgaria and Ankur in London as far as I know. So all of us are in UTC or UTC + 1. It would be great if a new moderators could be in an area around UTC +/- 10, but that should definitively not be the only approach how to vote on the 4th moderator. Other qualities are more important. And as a final remark: after all, we are a traveling site and we travel a lot. Also the current moderators sometime live in regions that are in other time zones than UTC (+ 1).

Comment: Thanks, I know this should definitely not be a decisive criteria. I just thought this is a useful piece of information when voting.

Comment: Bulgaria is two hours ahead of the UK.

Comment: And yesterday, daylight saving time began in the European Union and in Switzerland, so now they are at UTC+1, UTC+2 and UTC+3 until late October. :-)

Answer (score 11):

Having asked the question you linked to...

I'm less concerned about the time zone a moderator lives in, and more concerned about what times of day the moderator is most often active.

Someone in Europe who moderates while having breakfast is going to be doing so at about the same time as someone in Australia who moderates in the late afternoon, or a very late night owl in the US.

I mention this time period in particular because historically it's when we seem to get the plurality, if not the majority, of spam.